# Android краш приложение

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Ошибка вроде решена) поигрался с гредлом, удалил ненужные библиотеки (логику изменил а почистить не почистил). Вот теперь он выгляди вот так:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.5'

}
```

Всем спасибо! !

---

Помогите, сегодня пытался запустить приложение и выдает какую то ошибку, в интернете инфу по ней толком найти не могу. Может вы знаете в чем проблема ? 
Ошибка:

```
05-23 02:09:05.691 6577-6577/com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta, PID: 6577
                                                                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzi(Landroid/content/Context;I)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zznf; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.internal.zznf' appears in /data/data/com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-drive-8.1.0_b787c66db54cafae97319bce0ba9a47d96f21e74-classes.dex)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzd.zzks(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzp.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ListAllLeadershipActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_leadership"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailLeaderActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <!--
             ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
             App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.ReplacementActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_replacement"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity.NewsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity.DetailNews"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activity.MapActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activity.ContactActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activity.ApplicantsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.5'

}
```

Comment: Покажи код, что за статический метод zzi ты вызываешь?

Comment: Попробуйте отключить Instant run (File-Settings:Build, Execution, Deployment - Instant run - [_] Enable Instant Run...)

Comment: @Werder , в том и прикол, что его нет нигде

Comment: @YuraIvanov , сейчас попробую .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services` содержит в себе все библиотеки из этого списка 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Сократите импорт

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

до

```
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0')
```

или вместо `play-services` используйте индивидуальные библиотеки (с приставкой - `-ads`, `-gcm` и т.д.), по ссылки выше. Так же у вас `NoSuchMethodError` говорит о том, что не обнаружен метод в библиотеки `gms-play-services-drive`... как минимум вам нужно поднять версию `play-services` до `8.4.0`

Comment: все равно не помогает, вылетает другая ошибка. Только что попробовал запустить на эмуляторе андроид 5.1.1. - работает! А на 4х и 6х не хочет !(

Comment: а что теперь ?)

Comment: Все из за невнимательности, просто почистил зависимости и сделал rebuild .) спасибо